# Sorting/ordering List<object> with composite members and Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I am attempting to Sort a List of objects with composite members.  Although I can get this to work for member basic types (Person.EmployeeName), I do not know how to impalement this for composite memebers (Person.Employee.CompanyName).  I am creating a Lambda Expression var, and am sending that to into Order by.

Edit: I should add: This is called on the GridView Sort method. I did implement this using [ If (e.SortExpression == "Employee.CompanyName") { ... OrderBy(..Employee.CompanyName) } ] however it has been suggested (by my boss) to keep this dynamic.

```
public class Company {
    public string CompanyName;
}
public class Person {
    public Company Employee;
    public string EmployeeName;
}

public void LinqExpressionTest() {
    // Create List of people with Employeers
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person() { Employee = new Company { CompanyName = "Apple" } });
    people.Add(new Person() { Employee = new Company { CompanyName = "Microsoft" } });

    // Create Linq Lambda expression for sort based on Person.Employee.CompanyName
    // Error on next line because "Employee.CompanyName" is 'not defined for type Expression.Property'
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "Employee.CompanyName"); 
    Expression linqExpression = Expression.Property(param, "Employee.CompanyName");
    UnaryExpression unaryExpression = Expression.Convert(linqExpression, typeof(object));
    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>>(unaryExpression, param);

    var sortedPeople = people.AsQueryable<Person>().OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList();
}
```

Comment: OOI Why are you using an expression?

Comment: I am binding my List<object> to a gridview (using a custom CompositeBoundField property) and am sorting on the onPageIndexChanging event. e.SortExpression specifies the composite member.

Comment: I should add that this is the existing code, and I am open to a better solution.

Comment: I did implement this using a switch/case (Case "Person.EmployeeName": ..OrderBy(..e.SortExpression).. ) however it has been suggested I keep this more dynamic. (by my boss!)

Comment: I see. You need to dynamically sort your collection based on user input. Makes sense.

Comment: In the end I just implemented the switch/case pattern. Much simpler, and not a very good reason to go the other way.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you just want to sort your collection by Employee.CompanyName right?  Will the following work?

```
var sortedList = (from person in people
                 orderby person.Employee.CompanyName
                 select person).ToList()
```

Have a look at some of the samples over at [101Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#OrderBySimple1) - this one is an example of Linq orderby.

Comment: Yes it would, however It has been suggested (by my boss) that this should be dynamic.  Otherwise that would be a much better solution.

Comment: @davewilliams459 Can you explain what you mean when you say dynamic?  Cheers,

Comment: Able to specify the member to orderby using a string such as "Employee.CompanyName" rather than relying on hardcoded sorting options.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I see the benefits of making this 'dynamic' as you say.

How about the following which uses generics and a Func delegate - seems a bit extreme though and I have no idea if it'll work - i've just taken my previous query and created a method that'll pass in the key you want to order the list by:

```
    public IEnumerable<TSource> OrderList<TSource, TKey>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> list, 
        Func<TSource, TKey> sortFunction)
    {
        return from element in list
               orderby sortFunction
               select element;
    }
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
OrderList<Person, string>(people, (x)=>(x.Employee.CompanyName));
```

I don't see the benefit of using that over a Linq query though.